# Difference between returning 'const' or non-const reference

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, constants, pass-by-reference

I have a class with a list as member, and a getter on this list:

```
class A
{
public:
  const std::list<int*>& get() const {
    return list;
  }

private:
  std::list<int*> list;
};
```

Why the get function has to return a `const std::list` and not just an `std::list` ?

Otherwise I get this error :

> error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'std::list&'
>   from expression of type 'const std::list'

Comment: `const`-qualified `get` makes `this->list` `const`, so you can return only reference-to-const. Remove also the `const` qualifier (that is after the `()`) if you want to return reference-to-non-const.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the function `get` is declared as `const`:

```
const std::list<int*>& get() const
                          // ^
```

, so `list` is considered as a `const` inside the function.

Hence the attempt to return it as a non-const reference fails.

Comment: what is wrong with a list of int pointers? ( I know naked pointers are deprecated and whatever, but how does it relate to the validity of this question?)

Comment: @ForeverStudent Nothing is wrong with the list of pointers per se. It was a just typo in the original question, which is fixed now (one time `int` was used, another time `int*`.). I updated the post.

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem

The issue here is that `get` is `const` qualified, therefore it can only return a `const` reference to one of its member objects. If you want to return a non-const reference then you have to make `get` non `const`-qualified.

If you think about this also makes sense from the point of view of const-correctness: if you are allowed to return a non-const reference to a member object from a const qualified member function, then you can effectively modify a constant object via that reference, for example via:

```
A const a(...);
std::list<int*> ref = a.get(); // const qualified but returning non const reference
ref.clear(); // wiped out contents of list in `a`
```

#### Possible solutions

I'd recommend to provide both overloads as follows:

```
const std::list<int*>& get() const { return list; }
std::list<int*>& get() { return list; }
```

At this point it might be worth considering to just make the list public, depending on the context:

```
struct A {
    std::list<int*> list;
};
```